# Laravel: I'm retrieving two of the same model, it should be different. What is wrong with my find?

Tags: laravel

I should get two unique models. I'm searching for (e.g.) ID 1 and 2 in my table, but my result gets me two times of ID 1.

It should be quite easy but my solution doesn't work:

```
foreach($somearray as &$item){
    $item[1] = Sell::find($item[1])->with('user', 'sellImages', 'sellLinks')->first();
}
```

I have an array for example like that:

```
"items" => array:2 [▼
0 => array:2 [▼
  0 => 3
  1 => 1 //ID of Model
]
1 => array:2 [▼
  0 => 1
  1 => 2 //Id of Model
]
```

I don't know why, after the foreach I get the wrong model in somearray[1][1]. It's the same of somearray[0][1].

Why is it like that?

Comment: is the items array being passed in foreach ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to remove `->first()`. Then replace `with()` with `load()`.

You already get the model with `find()`. Calling `->first()` afterwards replaces it with the first model in the table (= the one with ID 1).

Comment: may I ask you to have a look at a Laravel join query related question here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52149031/laravel-join-query-with-conditions ?